# JQuery: Hide Div after function is performed (strange selector)

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I have quite a complex piece of code (JQuery and HTML5 Web SQL) that removes info from a database. However, whilst the database removal works fine I want to make the info disappear from view in the meantime (it wont go until the page refreshes and the database is queried again).

I'm pretty sure its just a matter of getting the selectors right

Currently I have

```
$('.remove_event').live('click', function() {
    //TRIGGERS SQL REMOVE
    mbffdb.webdb.deleteevent($(this).attr('id')),
    //MAKES INFO DISSAPPEAR
    $(this).attr('id').addClass('displaynone');
});//END CLICK
```

The info is cotained in a div that is given a dynamic id
: `$(this).attr('id')` (the ID is used in the SQL statement to remove).

If anyone can help me that would be really awesome!

Comment: can't use `this.id` from one elemnt to use as ID for another element. ID's have to be unique so either details need clarifying or you are duplicating ID's

Comment: @charlietfl is right - all of the elements you display **HAVE** to be with unique IDs. If they're not this usually causes browser misbehavior as it doesn't know which element to process. This will be a problem if you're trying to operate directly to the element via `$("#my_id_that_exists_many_times")`.

Comment: perhaps I'm wrong but my interpretation is the element needed is not the element being clicked and everyone else is adding class to `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, you add a class... to a string. 
Follow me:

```
$(this)
```

is an element

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

is the value of it's attribute "id", i.e. a string so you can't add a class to it.

By the way, do you want to add an *id* or a *class*? it's not clear. If you want to add an id, use `.attr("id","mynewid")`. If you want to add a class, use `$(this).addClass("class")`

---

Edit: you may have been misled by JQuery's chainability, i.e. many functions operating on a JQUery element or set of elements return another element or set of elements.

For example:

```
$("div.mydiv").parent().next().find("p").removeClass("otherclass");
              ^        ^      ^         ^
```

In every call (^) the functions return *other* elements so you can attach *another* function to operate on those elements, yieling more elements and so on.
But this is not true for some of the functions like:

```
.val() .text() .html()
```

that return "pure" values, not elements, so there's no sense in using, after them, functions like `addClass()` which still operate con elements.

Comment: `val(), text() and html()` can be chained if they are used as setters

Comment: Right :) I was obviously talking about their "getter" form, but I have oversimplified.

Answer (score 2):

Change `$(this).attr('id').addClass('displaynone');` to this `$(this).addClass('displaynone');`

Comment: @iambriansreed `.on()` is not available in jQuery < 1.7

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.remove_event').live('click', function() {
    // $(this) refers to the element that was clicked.
    // $(this).attr('id') will return the attribute "id" of the element

    // TRIGGERS SQL REMOVE
    // the line below will execute the "deleteevent" function
    // passing the attribute id of $(this) as a parameter.
    mbffdb.webdb.deleteevent($(this).attr('id')),

    // MAKES INFO DISSAPPEAR
    // the line below will not work because you're trying to add a class 
    // to a non-element. ($(this).attr('id') returns the attribute! 
    // you can't chain!)
    // $(this).attr('id').addClass('displaynone');

    // Instead you should use this line 
    // which will add a class "displaynone" to the element $(this)
    $(this).addClass('displaynone');
    // or you can also set 'style="display:none;"' by doing
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});//END CLICK
```